# MySQL to JSON results in empty Google visualisation chart(no data)

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using the following code to create a pie chart from data extracted from a database:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var col=<?php echo json_encode($aColumn); ?>;
    var jsonString = <?php echo json_encode($v); ?>;    //Access PHP variable in JavaScript JSON STRING
    var jsonArray=JSON.parse(jsonString);

    var options = {
      pieHole: 0.5,
      pieSliceTextStyle: {
        color: 'black',
      },
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var testArray = [[col,"COUNT"]];

    $.each(jsonArray, function() {
      var item = [this[col],this.TOTAL]; //document.write(item);
      testArray.push(item);
    });

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([testArray]);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donut'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

When I try to plot this data in a Google Visualisation LineChart, the chart is empty. Just no data is printed on page.

This is my first time working on PHP so I'm probably missing something really obvious. Any help would be appreciated though.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways.

1 - In your code the line 7 "var jsonString" already is a object/array, so you don't need the line 8, because if you don't use quotes, the Javascript is going to understand as object/array and just don't need to make parse. So, your output will be something like this:

```
var jsonString = [...];
```

2 - Now, to Javascript understand string, you need put quotes on line 7, like this:

```
var jsonString = "<?php echo json_encode($v); ?>";
```

The output should be something like that:

```
var jsonString = "[...]";
```

In 2nd case, you need parse.

Comment: I just commented the 8th line and changed my code


`function drawChart() {`
 `var jsonString = <?php echo json_encode($v); ?>;    `
       `  //var jsonArray=JSON.parse(jsonString);`
 `var testArray = [[col,"COUNT"]];`

 `$.each(jsonString, function() {`
  `var item = [this[col],this.TOTAL]; `      
  `testArray.push(item);`
    ` });`

                                                             Still the same error coming.

Comment: You tried <?php var_dump($v);  ?> out of tag <script> to see what PHP returns?

Comment: What is the error you got? Do you checked if you got error at javascript console of browser (F12)?

Comment: Yes `<?php var_dump($v); ?>` 
is working fine, returning required output in String.

the google map div is showing **no data**.
the console is showing some 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined  error.**